# Set Date to the Jquery UI datepicker input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker.and its working fine .my need is to set the date to the textbox when querystring contain any date

eg my url is `localhost:301/?date=2013-12-01`

so I want to set this date to input textbox.

my input box html is

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="txt-cal hasDatepicker" name="addFromDate" date_name="2013-12-11">
```

I tried some thing but no result.

```
$(function () {

        var myDate = ?/*how to select the date_name from input textbox
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
        $('#datepicke3').datepicker();
        $('#datepicke3').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
        $('#datepicker4').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker4').datepicker('setDate', myDate);


    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle? You should call `.datepicker() `first and then `.datepicker('setDate', date)` on it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D9N6a/2/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/D9N6a/3/

Comment: set your date format `dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd' ` then you can assign you date value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach will be using [custom **`data`** attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

```
data-date="2013-12-11"
```

Now you can access it

```
var myDate = $("#datepicker").data("date");
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
```

**Update:**

I doubt you're trying to get it from url(ie, query string)

If so check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1671639), where a method is written to get

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Now

```
var myDate = getParameterByName("date");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .attr function:

```
var myDate = $("#datepicker").attr("date_name");
```

However, you should beware of creating non-standard HTML attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

$('#datepicker1').datepicker({ orientation: 'top', format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = ((currentDate.getDate()).toString().length == 1) ? '0' + (currentDate.getDate()).toString() : (currentDate.getDate()).toString();
var month = ((currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1) ? '0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
$("#datepicker1").val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
```

I have tried in text input control. It just needed to apply datepicker 1st then set the current date to textbox.